# How to capture all letters from different languages in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a corpus of different texts from different languages.
I want to capture all characters. I use **python 2.7** and **defaultencodingsetting** is **utf-8**.
I do not know why when I use this code for German umlaut it prints out German umlaut correctly :

```
'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

Result is: 
**Erdäpfel**

but when I use this code :

```
'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

result is :
**ErdÃ¤pfel** which is different.

I am not familiar with text mining.I know that for example latin1 encoding does not contain French letter which is not desired in my project.
How can I convert all unicode escape strings in my corpus regardless of their language to respective character?

**Utf-8** according to documentations contains all languages but why it does not print out German umlaut correctly while latin1 encoding prints out correctly?

**PS: Lowercase in unicode escaping characters sequences is not the case. I have tried both and results were the same.**

Comment: `'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'` is **already** UTF-8, decoding as `unicode-escape` is basically the same as decoding as Latin-1..

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *already* have UTF-8 encoded data. There are no string literal characters to escape in your bytestring. You are looking at the `repr()` output of a string where non-printable ASCII characters are shown as escape sequences because that makes the value easily copy-pastable in an ASCII-safe way. The `\xc3` you see is *one byte*, not separate characters:

```
>>> 'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'
'Erd\xc3\xa4pfel'
>>> 'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'[3]
'\xc3'
>>> 'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'[4]
'\xa4'
>>> print 'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'
Erdäpfel
```

You'd have to use a raw string literal or doubled backslashes to actually getting escape sequences that `unicode-escape` would handle:

```
>>> '\\xc3\\xa4'
'\\xc3\\xa4'
>>> '\\xc3\\xa4'[0]
'\\'
>>> '\\xc3\\xa4'[1]
'x'
>>> '\\xc3\\xa4'[2]
'c'
>>> '\\xc3\\xa4'[3]
'3'
>>> print '\\xc3\\xa4'
\xc3\xa4
```

Note how there is a separate `\` backslash character in that string (echoed as `\\`, *escaped* again).

Next to interpreting actual escape sequences he `unicode-escape` decodes your data as Latin-1, so you end up with a Unicode string with the character [U+00C3 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE](https://codepoints.net/U+00C3) in it. Encoding that back to Latin-1 bytes gives you the `\xC3` byte again, and you are back to UTF-8 bytes. Decoding then as UTF-8 works correctly.

But your second attempt encoded the U+00C3 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE codepoint to UTF-8, and *that* encoding gives you the byte sequence `\xc3\x83`. Printing those bytes to your UTF-8 terminal will show the `Ã` character. The other byte, `\xA4` became [U+00A4 CURRENCY SIGN](https://codepoints.net/U+00A4), and the UTF-8 byte sequence for that is `\xc2\xa4`, which prints as `¤`.

There is *absolutely no need* to decode as `unicode-escape` here. Just leave the data *as is*. Or, perhaps, decode as UTF-8 to get a `unicode` object:

```
>>> 'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'.decode('utf8')
u'Erd\xe4pfel'
>>> print 'Erd\xC3\xA4pfel'.decode('utf8')
Erdäpfel
```

If your **actual** data (and not the test you did) contains `\xhh` escape sequences that encode UTTF-8, then don't use `unicode-escape` to decode those sequences *either*. Use `string-escape` so you get a byte string containing UTF-8 data (which you can then decode to Unicode as needed):

```
>>> 'Erd\\xc3\\xa4pfel'
'Erd\\xc3\\xa4pfel'
>>> 'Erd\\xc3\\xa4pfel'.decode('string-escape')
'Erd\xc3\xa4pfel'
>>> 'Erd\\xc3\\xa4pfel'.decode('string-escape').decode('utf8')
u'Erd\xe4pfel'
>>> print 'Erd\\xc3\\xa4pfel'.decode('string-escape').decode('utf8')
Erdäpfel
```

Comment: Thx for nice explanation. It worked without decode unicode escape and It captures many different letters but stil for example I have such a string  **\xedcies,informaci\xf3,v\xeddeos,fotos,\xe0udios,gr\xe0fics** What is this?

Comment: @Kaggle: I don't know; that's way too little info to go on. How is that string displayed? Is it a `repr()` echo? (When you echo a value in the interactive interpreter or you print a container, you see `repr()` output). If so, does that representation start with `u` perhaps? Python 2 will always only show ASCII printable characters in such string representations, everything else will use an escape sequence (up to U+00FF Unicode, you get `\xhh` sequences, after that you get `\uhhhh` and `\Uhhhhhhhh`).

Comment: @Kaggle: I suspect you are looking at a `unicode` string representation (`u'...'`), at which point seeing `\xed` and `\xf3` is *normal*; you are seeing Latin-1 characters; print that string and you'll see `ícies,informació,vídeos,fotos,àudios,gràfics` output.

Comment: I just simply print it. It does not start with u.

Comment: @Kaggle: So what does `print repr(value)` produce? Double backslashes? Because then you actually *do* have literal escape sequences in that data. And that data appears to be Latin-1 encoded in that case.

Comment: When I printed out repr(value) it produced string with **u**  at the begining So it is unicode.There are many special characters which are printed out correctly like German umlaut and chinise letter and ... but I think there are some problem with French words.

Comment: **u'Erd\\xC3\\xA4pfel** it is what repr produces

Comment: @Kaggle: where is this data coming from? Because *that* is a valid `unicode-escape` string. That, or `string-escape`-ed Latin-1 data.

Comment: We are crawling many web sites.There is a massive amount of data.In the larg corpus in text mining is there a generic way to capture all characters in all languages?

Comment: @Kaggle: no, in the mixed bag that is the web, there is no fool-proof way to detect the correct encoding of a page every single time. The web doesn't use `\xhh` escape codes however, that smells like something your code does later.

Comment: @Kaggle: encodings and language are *independent*. Sure, you must use a codec that can handle all characters typically used in a language, but it doesn't matter to UTF-8 what language the text is in since it can encode all of Unicode. You have merely been lucky or haven't looked far enough.